# Attempting to connect to TFS closes solution

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to connect to TFS with a solution that already exists within _.visualstudio.com .
However, I can't commit any changes to it, because TFS simply won't connect to it.

If I try to connect to TFS with my solution opened, it closes.

If I try to open the solution with TFS connected, it disconnects.

Driving me crazy here.

Solutions, please....

Using VS2013 Professional. A few projects (not this one) uses GIT.

Comment: Realize this is kinda old, but in 2019 I hit a similar issue that hitting Options >>> Preview Features >>> and unchecking _New Git user experience_ seems to have fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Apparently, VS2013 has an issue with GIT, althought unreported. I tried to work with GIT when VS 2013 was launched at its first version, and it was... well... flawed. ".aspx.cs" files weren't always included when commits were done, files were missing, resources, lost... I always ended up using GIT's BASH , but that's not the point.

I noticed that, when I had a solution opened, and attempted to connect it to TFS (TEAM > Connect to TFS), it automatically opened GIT's repository interface. At first, I didn't notice it, since  GIT's and TFS' screens are very much the same: Git's doesn't have the "Source Control Explorer" button.

When I first noticed it, I proceeded to "remove" all the repositories I could find in that damned Team explorer View,... but when I closed VS2013 and opened it again, there was a new one, named after my user. "C:\Users\Username". ... There was no option to "Remove" it, as the others had... And the problem persisted.

**I finally deleted the hidden .git folder there, and now the TFS works perfectly.**

I don't know whether this can be a solution to anyone not willing to risk their .git repositories... but it worked for me. I backed up all I had, and crossed my fingers. 
GIT, only outside VS2013 now.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is currently bound to a different Source Control or TFS. If you open the solution and go to File | Source Control | Change Source Control you should see where it is connected.

From there you can unbind from the current TFVC project.

Comment: I tried to open this menu, but it seems like I can only access it when I'm on Source Control Explorer, pointing to the solution. Even there, the only options I have are FIND and ADVANCED. 
If I try to open the solution, the "Source Control" option vanishes from the menu.